# Microsoft Graph get attachment data for mails and events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I understand that to use the /attachments API, an id of the event or message which has an attachment needs to be passed. Can attachment data for an event or message be obtained without this dependency? For example, when I'm making a  call to /events API for a particular user, along with events data for that user, can I also get attachment data associated with the event?
I'm using client credentials flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by explicitly specifying that you'd like to include attachments the response body using the OData [expand](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752359) query option.

In your case, the request URI would look as follows: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=attachments`

Comment: Can something similar be done to get eventMessage data?

Comment: Could you provide more context about the scenario? Is the question whether it's possible to get email messages and expand the 'event' on just the event messages?

Comment: Yes Dmitry, is it possible to expand event on just the event messages?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to conditionally expand on the /messages endpoint since it returns the base type `message`. The event property is only available on the derived type called `eventMessage`. This scenario is good feedback for us, nonetheless.

Comment: Is there a way to know if data returned by /messages corresponds to an event or not?

Comment: The entity will have an a type annotation as follows:  `"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessage"`

Comment: this helped a lot. Like you mentioned earlier, it would be great if you can expand eventMessage from /messages endpoint